# juju end point does NOT setup do to access to https:/streams/cannoical/com - ppc64el

Tags: juju, maas, ppc64le

**Explanation:**

I work for IBM and trying to prototype netboot (pxe) for ubuntu.  This question is used to identify some issue involved in setting up juju end point client provisioning (for jujud).

**Activity**

As part of prototype trying to use juju to deploy to end point.  Could occur
on a bootstrap or add-machine.   This process was using the manual environment.
The 4 VMs needed were previously provisioned by maas.

juju bootstrap --show-log --debug -e manual

or

juju add-machine ssh:root@x.x.x.x --show-log --debug

**Problem**

```
       juju end point does NOT setup do to access to https:/streams/cannoical/com
```

On endpoint check /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: //curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
tools from //streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.24.6-trusty-ppc64el.tgz downloaded: HTTP 000; time 0.006s; size 0 bytes; speed 0.000 bytes/s sha256sum: /var/lib/juju/tools/1.24.6-trusty-ppc64el/tools.tar.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: Answer is provided in the question to document resolution of problem

Comment: Can you reformat this to be an actual question? This is a Q&A site, entries should follow that format.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution:**

On endpoint check /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

If cloud-init-output.log contains below you need to add CA certificate to talk to the

https://streams.canonical.com.

1. You can do this via x11 interface, bring up firefox and then add certificate via firefox.  See How do I setup vnc for ppc64 ubuntu? on how to setup x11 for vnc (if ppc64le) because normal vncserver does not work.
2. In Firefox use this as address: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.24.6-trusty-ppc64el.tgz.  Now add the certificate.
3. If well versed in adding certificates to a server you can proceed to do it
   that way too.

Note that is is possible the certificate was OK but company firewall access was lost (for IBM this is called BSO.  This is the second reason that doing bootstrap for target host may fail.  If you did above procedure and have to do it second time you will see the BSO access input. Just

satisfied that and redo the juju bootstrap.